# Gradle dependencies not working with import statements in IntelliJ

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm working on a JSP site in IntelliJ, and I'm adding Gradle to help automate my builds. However, after replacing the manual dependencies in the project with Gradle dependencies, the import statements in the jsp files don't work. The import statements are grey and "unused", and the classes from those dependencies aren't detected. It seems like Gradle has added the dependencies to the project fine, they're just something wrong between the dependency and the import statement.